# PHP: How to check/use external resources in a nonblocking way

Tags: php, resources, external, nonblocking

I want to set up a small banner exchange. I wrote a PHP site for that purpose which can be included into the actual website where the banners should be displayed.

As default I want to load the banners from the respective remote location as they change every now and then (with the url staying the same) and only fall back to a local copy when the live version is not available. (Before anyone objects - the server owners are fine with this)

My problem is, that every attempt to check for the external availability leads to the script taking several seconds to load. And when I include said script into the main website it delays the whole page to be properly rendered/loaded.

Can anyone give a good advice on how to solve this? I want to check the external resources and use them if there. If they ain't reachable (either server offline, resource renamed/moved, ...) then the local copy should be used.

```
$url = http://some.address/image.jpg
if (@getimagesize($url)) { use live version }
else { use local version }
```

That (yeah, pseudocode) was my idea of testing. I thought that this checks if the resource is there and also checks that the returned resource is an image and no error-page etc. But guess I was wrong.

Comment: getimagesize will download the entire file first before processing it. plus if that url is offline, your script will block until everything times out.

Comment: Okay, that explains it, thanks. Any suggestion on what to use instead?

Comment: you'd be better off simply serving up a locally cached copy every time, and have a separate script do update checks to see if the remote copy has changed. then you have no worries about holding up regular users.